# Booting harddrive fails (sound+video)

Tags: hard-drive, boot

My harddrive, is not recognized and doesn't seem to boot.

Here is a video:
http://youtu.be/z7zNIwq1HiI

What is that and how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was curious at work so i took apart a hard drive with the same problem.
That little black thing moving to the left of the read/write arm, that is a lock that keeps the arm from moving. if you push it so that it releases the lock it will release the arm and it can move again.

Comment: Would you please make a screen, as I don't know exactly what you mean by that.

Comment: Move the black arm aside but be very careful as to not touch the disk, i have linked a picture with a description

http://i33.photobucket.com/albums/d89/Eryper/stuckharddrive.png
this arm is designed to use the Air pressure generated from the spinning disk to release it self, if the cover is off it will not release so you have to do it manually.

Comment: Hello Eryper, this method sounds like a solution. But when I move it aside, it won't boot. The arm moves a little further then before, but still no booting made.

Comment: This video was done, after my last comment: http://youtu.be/FkYO5zeN6hc It shows, that even if the arm moves free, it still does not boot.

Comment: I was afraid that it wasn't the stuck arm causing it. Now we need to go into more detailed hard drive troubleshooting. Do you have a external drive reader? if not can you plug the drive into another PC as a Secondary drive to see if windows can pick it up as a additional internal disk. If so then you need to run a check disk on that drive. If the check disk does not resolve the boot problem then you need to perform either a windows boot file repair or a complete windows install, both can be chosen when booting from a Windows Install disk. Keep me updated.

Comment: I've got an external drive reader **and** an other pc. But first we should try the external drive reader. And with doing that, this happens: Drive spins up, but hardware manager doesn't recognize it.

Comment: What was this drive doing before it began not booting? Also what kind of errors was it getting? If you want to try something else you can add the hard drive as a secondary directly connected to the mobo and then check disk management if it detects it. An external drive reader will not show up in disk management as a second disk.

Comment: Idk what the drive was before and what errors came before. It looks like an old system drive to me. (I found it on the attic - but it's mine though). I will attach it to an old computer. Thank you (will keep this thread updated)